Hyphens and two-word nouns
I have been reading almost all the rules on hyphens I could find, but I am still unsure about some examples pertaining two nouns that consist of two words. Which of the following variants would be preferable:

I am doing machine learning research.
I am doing machine-learning research.

I tend towards 1. because the noun is machine learning, and, to my understanding, there is no ambiguity in the phrasing, rendering the hyphen redundant. Is my reasoning correct and could someone point me towards an authoritative source?

Are you aiming at a readership who knows what "machine learning" is?


Is correct, but "machine-learning" is not a compound noun but a verb-centred compound adjective. Other similar verb-centred compound adjectives include", cost-cutting" and "fact-learning". Note the hyphens.


@KillingTime Yes, I am.

@BillJ Sorry, I'm not sure I understand this. I'd reformulate the sentence as "A researcher in machine learning." Your other examples do not necessarily work like this unless I'm mistaken.

Yes, for 'cost-cutting' at least: 'an exercise in cost cutting'. In this sentence, the hyphen is optional Many would here see cost[-]cutting as a compound noun, optionally open or hyphenated.

@Gnosophilon Your reformulated example uses "machine-learning" as object of the preposition "in", where it is thus a compound noun (compare also "... in dressmaking", "... in star-gazing", both compound nouns). But your original examples used "machine-learning" as an attributive modifier of the noun "research", and thus it is a compound adjective. It consists of the noun "machine" as the first component and the gerund-participle verb "cutting" as head.

Thanks for the clarification!
